# Laravel 5.1 - Has many relationship returning 0 when using existence query

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

So I have a Vip model:

```
class Vip extends Model
{
    use MemberTypeTrait;
    use RecordStatusActiveTrait;

    protected $table = 'fm_vip_demographics';
    protected $primaryKey = 'vip_id';

    public function dependents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Dependent', 'group_id');
    }

    public function spouses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Dependent', 'group_id')->spouses();
    }
}
```

In this model I have a relationship to a "Dependent" model that is related to the vip through its group id. This "Dependent" model also has a scope called `scopeSpouses` that only finds spouse dependents (dead / divorced and current).

```
class Dependent extends Model
{
    use DependentTypeTrait;

    protected $table = 'fm_vip_demographics';
    protected $primaryKey = 'vip_id';

    public function scopeSpouses($query)
    {
        // relationship id's 3 and 14 are spouse-type relationships
        return $query->whereIn('relationship_id', [3, 14]);
    }

    public function vip()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Vip', 'group_id');
    }
}
```

Now in a controller I am trying to find all the vip's that have spouses. I am trying this:

`$vips = (new \App\Models\Vip)->has('spouses')->get(); dd($vips);`

This is returning null even though i am positive that I have vip's with spouses that are set up correctly. If I grab a specific vip and do `$vip->spouses;` I get the spouses back correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

**Update:**

I also have tried using the regular `dependents` relationship that does not use a query scope in the relationship and am having the same issue.

`$vips = (new \App\Models\Vip)->has('dependents')->get();`

**Update 2:**

It might be worth noting that both the Vip model and the Dependent model both are the same table. Vip's have a vip_type_id of 3 while dependents have a vip_type_id of 1 and are associated to their vip through group_id. Therefore dependent with id of 666 has a a group_id of 69 which actually points to another person in the same table with an id of 69. If you have any questions please feel free to ask them in the comments.

Also I realize this would be a good use of a polymorphic relationship except that I am not allowed to change the database schema so that is not an option.

To clarify this relationship I have added in the table name and id's as they are set up in my actual model.

**Update 3:**

I have attempted to Eager load my model with dependents and spouses using `with()` and it works just fine. This means that I can use this relationship for eager loading and a single call but when I try to filter using `has()` it breaks and returns an empty set. I still don't know why.

**Update 4:**

I looked at the query and found something unusual. The query has 6 bindings yet there are 7 keys in the binding array. I think this is screwing it up as binding key '4' is incorrect but im not sure why this is happening.

query log output:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `fm_vip_demographics` where `vip_type_id` = ? and `fm_vip_demographics`.`record_status` = ? and (select count(*) from `fm_vip_demographics` as `self_3005b65b2c6b3cccca2d6b3b119f3570` where `self_3005b65b2c6b3cccca2d6b3b119f3570`.`group_id` = `fm_vip_demographics`.`vip_id` and `vip_type_id` = ? and `fm_vip_demographics`.`record_status` = ? and `relationship_id` in (?, ?)) >= 1"
    "bindings" => array:7 [
      0 => 3
      1 => 1
      2 => 1
      3 => 2
      4 => 1
      5 => 3
      6 => 14
    ]
    "time" => 0.28
  ]
]
```

If I use this query manually and get rid of index 4 in the bindings it works perfectly.

Comment: the problem is not the `new` keyword as I said in another comment. Sorry for that. The problem is in the relationship itself. After defining a relationship you want to add a **scope** (`spouses`) but it doesn't work like that.

Comment: Actually it works fine.....I am also having an issue on my normal `dependents` relationship that uses the SAME model but without the scope.